# Interaction between forms — How to change a control of a form from another form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to set comboBox.SelectedValue when I select the row in my dataGridView on first form to populate comboBox with that value on another form,

On second form in my load event I have `comboBox.DataSource`, `DisplayMember`, `ValueMember` set it correctly but nothing is happening when I set selectedValue on first. Everything works great when I do it on one form

Comment: As an option you can pass the value to constructor of your new form. Then you can store it in a member field and use it in `Load` event.

Comment: I really have no Idea how to do that I don't work so much with forms ?

Comment: Such question has been asked many times, For example this post may be a possible duplicate: [Passing Values Between Windows Forms c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836398/passing-values-between-windows-forms-c-sharp) Also this one: [How to pass values between forms in c# windows application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205195/how-to-pass-values-between-forms-in-c-sharp-windows-application). *But* I also believe the current answer is good enough to be a separate post, it contains some useful options for different cases.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`Form`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) in Windows Forms is a class like other C# classes. The way of communicating between forms are the same as classes. You can consider this options when communicating between classes:

**Manipulate second Form from first Form**

- You can add suitable parameters to the constructor of the second form. Then you can pass values to the constructor when creating an instance of the second form. In the second form store parameters in member fields and use them when you nees.
- You can create public property or method in the second form and set those properties after creating an instance of the second form. This way you can use them when you need in the second form. This option is not limited to passing values when creating the second form. You can even use that property during the execution of second `Form`. Also it's useful for getting a value from it.
- As another option you can make the control which you want to manipulate it public and this way you can access to it from other form. Using a method is a more recommended way of doing this.

**Manipulate first Form from second form**

- You can create a public method or property in first form and pass an instance of the first form to second form. Then using that method/property on the passed instance, you can manipulate the first form.
- You can create an event in second form and after creating an instance of second form subscribe for it in first form and put the code for changing the form in the handler. Then it's enough to raise the event in second form.
- You can define a public property of type `Action` or some other delegate type in second form and then after creating an instance of second form, assign the property using a custom action. Then in second form, it's enough to invoke the action when you need to manipulate first form.
- Also here you can make a control of first form to be public and then if you pass an instance of the first form to the second form, you can manipulate the control. It's recommended to use other solutions. It's like creating public property or method, but a method which performs specific task on the control is better that exposing the whole control. But you may need this solution some times.

Here are some useful examples about above solutions.

### **Manipulate second Form from first Form**

**Example1 - Using constructor of second Form**

Use this example when you need to pass some data to second form, when creating the second form.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    int selectedValue;
    public Form2(int value)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        selectedValue = value;
    }
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Load data
        this.comboBox1.DataSource = new MyDbContext().Categories.ToList();
        this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
        this.comboBox1.SelectedValue = selectedValue;
    }
}
```

Then in your first form, it's enough to pass the value to `Form2` when you create a new instance of it:

```
var value = 2; // Or get it from grid
var f = new Form2(value);
f.ShowDialog();
```

**Example2 - using public Property or Method of second Form**

Use this example when you need to pass some data to second form, when creating or even after creation of second form.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string SomeValue
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text;}
        set { textBox1.Text = value;}
    }
}
```

Then in your first form, it's enough to pass the value to `Form2` when you need, after creating `Form2` or whenever you need to set value of `textBox1` on `Form2`:

```
var f = new Form2(); //value is not needed here
f.SomeValue = "some value";
f.Show();
//...
f.SomeValue = "some other value";
```

**Example 3 - Making a Control of Second form  public**

Use this example when you need to change a property of a control on second form, when creating or even after creation of second form. It's better to use public property or method instead of exposing whole control properties.

In your `Form`, at designer, select the control and in Properties window set the `Modifiers` property to `Public`. Also make sure the `GenerateMember` property is `true`. Then you can simply access this control using its name from outside of the `Form`.

```
var f = new Form2();
f.textBox1= "some value";
```

### **Manipulate first Form from second form**

**Example 4 - Create public Method or Property in first Form and pass an instance of First Form to constructor of second Form**

Use this example when you need to change first `Form` from second Form.

In your `Form1`, create a property of a method that accepts some parameters and put the logic in it:

```
public void ChangeTextBox1Text(string text)
{
    this.textBox1.Text = text;
}
```

Then create a constructor in `Form2` which accepts a parameter of type `Form1` and keep the passed value in a member field and use it when you need:

```
Form1 form1;
public Form2 (Form1 f)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    form1 = f; 
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form1.ChangeTextBox1Text("Some Value");
}
```

Now when creating `Form2` you should pass an instance of `Form1` to it:

```
var f = new Form2(this);
f.Show();
```

**Example 5 - Using event of second Form in first Form**

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483278/how-do-i-feed-values-to-the-statusstrip-from-a-form-control). It's about communication between form and a control, but it's applicable to communication between forms also.

**Example 6 - Injection an Action in second Form**

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483278/how-do-i-feed-values-to-the-statusstrip-from-a-form-control). It's about communication between form and a control, but it's applicable to communication between forms also.

**Example 7 - Making a Control of first form  public**

In this solution you need to make a control in first form public, like example 3. Then like example 4 pass an instance of the first form to second form and keep it in a field and use it when you need. Using a public method or property is preferred.

```
Form1 form1;
public Form2 (Form1 f)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    form1 = f; 
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form1.textBox1.Text = "Some Value";
}
```

when creating `Form2` you should pass an instance of `Form1` to it:

```
var f = new Form2(this);
f.Show();
```

Comment: I clicked up is that I have two combo and just pass two values saved my time thx again man

Comment: Ok I press thic green check now

Comment: Thx you man saved my time and apology for last quest you were right I am still learning I hope you understand

Comment: It's OK, don't worry about it :) - By the way, you can also delete your irrelevant or obsolete comments.

Comment: Really useful answer. Thanks. Please notice that In example 2, `value` is not needed when creating an instance of `Form2`.