# How can I do data synchronization between two child form inside parent container winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have this situation I want to synchronize informations in my dataGridView  when I insert it on my add form like you can see on this picture.[image]

In my Insert form on insert button I call Add form to pop up like this

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (addForm==null)
        {
            addForm = new AddForm();
        }
        addForm.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
        addForm.FormClosed += AddForm_FormClosed;
        addForm.Show();

    }

    private void AddForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        addForm = null;
    }
```

On Add form in Accept click I insert informations and call fillDataGrid() method from Insert form to do data sync but nothing is shown data is shown just when I close Insert form and call it again does someone has susggestion how can I do this this is the first time I work with MdiContainer ?

```
private void buttonAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (validation())
        {
            Proizvod product = new Proizvod();
            product.NazivProizvoda = textBoxName.Text;
            product.Opis = textBoxDescription.Text;
            product.SerijskiBroj = textBoxNumber.Text;
            product.ZemljaPorijekla = textBoxCountry.Text;

            if (pDal.insertProduct(product)==0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Informations are successfully inserted","Message");
                InsertForm inForm = new InsertForm();
                inForm.fillDataGrid();
            }
        }
    }
```

My fillDataGrid() method and Load event of InsertForm:

```
 public void fillDataGrid()
    {
        dataGridViewProducts.DataSource = null;
        dataGridViewProducts.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridViewProducts.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dataGridViewProducts.ColumnCount = 3;

        dataGridViewProducts.Columns[0].Name = "Product name";
        dataGridViewProducts.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "NazivProizvoda";
        dataGridViewProducts.Columns[1].Name = "Country";
        dataGridViewProducts.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "ZemljaPorijekla";
        dataGridViewProducts.Columns[2].Name = "Product number";
        dataGridViewProducts.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "SerijskiBroj";
        dataGridViewProducts.DataSource = pDal.getAllProducts();
    }

    private void InsertForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fillDataGrid();
    }

    private void InsertForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridViewProducts.CurrentCell = null;
        dataGridViewProducts.ClearSelection();
    }
```

Comment: The model (database stuff) can provide `ProductAdded` event, when something calls model method `AddProduct(product)` then add product and rise that event.

Comment: Sorry @Sinatr I really have no idea how to do that you mean for me to write my delegate and event

Comment: Currently in `buttonAccept_Click` code, you have created a new instance of the list form and called its `FillGrid`. This way you are manipulating another instance of the list form which is different from the instance which is open and you can see.

Comment: Instead of creating another instance of your list form, pass the current instance to the constructor of your second form and keep it in a member field and then in save button, call the fill grid method using that instance. Read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38769212/3110834). Specially this part **Manipulate first Form from second form:** *The first option is useful for this case: You can create a public method or property in first form and pass an instance of the first form to second Form. Then using that method/property on the passed instance, you can manipulate the first form.*

Comment: Thx man I will you are the lifesaver

Comment: @jhony3 I added an example in the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently in `buttonAccept_Click` code, you have created a new instance of the list form and called its `FillGrid`. This way you are manipulating another instance of the list form which is different from the instance which is open and you can see. You are filling a different form which you didn't show it.

Instead of creating a new instance, create a constructor for your second form which accepts a parameter of first form type. Then when you want to create a new instance of seccod form, pass the instance of the first form (`this`) to second Form. Then in your save button call the `FillGrid` method of the passed instance.

For more information about how to manipulate another form, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38769212/3110834). It contains some useful options about:

- Pass data to second Form when creating
- Manipulate second Form after showing
- Manipulate first Form from second Form

Here is some code which belong to the `ListForm`:

```
private void ShowAddForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (addForm == null)
    {
        addForm = new AddForm(this);
        addForm.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
        addForm.FormClosed += AddForm_FormClosed;
    }
    addForm.Show();
}
private void AddForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    addForm = null;
}
```

And here is the code for `AddForm`

```
public class AddForm
{
    MyListForm listForm;
    public AddForm(MyListForm f)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listForm = f;
    }
    private void SaveVutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //perform validation and save data
        f.FillGrid();
    }
}
```

Comment: Man thx a lot this works I used to work with `if(form.showdialog()==DialogResult.Yes){  //on first form I fill data }` and on second form I have `if(validation()){this.dialogResult=DialogResult.Yes;}` this is the first on this way

Comment: You are welcome, I also prefer to use `ShowDialog`. But also the above example is a corrected version of your code :)