# VB.Net passing datagridview row from one form to another form that is already open

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to develop a search window that allows a user to fill in criteria, then click the search button. When the search button is clicked the results are returned in a `DataGridView`. When a result in the `DataGridView` is clicked, I'd like to pass the row number to another form that is already open.

I understand I can pass the result by creating a new instance of the form. I pass variables to my Search Window using the following method:

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click

        Dim ST = New Search_Tool(DGV_Ongoing.DataSource, AgencyOptions, EthnicityOptions, EmploymentTypeOptions, EmploymentStatusOptions,
                                         CategoryOptions, OutcomeOptions)

        ST.Show()

    End Sub
```

however I cannot call the form I want to pass the row value to because it is already open (its the main form). Is there a way to handle this? I'm struggling to find any information that doesn't call the form to open it whilst passing the data.

I can't reference `Main_form.Main_DGV.CurrentCell` as Visual Studio says it requires an Object Reference in order to do so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could expose a property on the search form to fetch the answer.  Your `ST` object may need to be other than local.  Also rather than returning a visual object, consider returning something like an Id or array of IDs

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38769212/3110834) for some good options.

Comment: From a users point of view: Wouldn´t it be smoother to search at the same place where the data is shown? So to be able to set filters directly above the grid?

Comment: Alex B. - it would, but this search tool has more than just filters and has 40 options available to the user. It's cleaner to have it in a floating form than can be minimised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend an event in your Search_Tool form that is raised when the user has found what they're looking for.

The main form is subscribed to that and can then access its datagrid.

```
Class Search_Tool
    Inherits Form

    Public Event SearchResultFound(resultId As Integer)

    Private Sub OnUserClickedARowOrPressedAButtonOrWhatever()
        RaiseEvent SearchResultFound(currentRow.Id)
    End Sub

End Class
```

And in the main form.

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click

    Dim ST = New Search_Tool(DGV_Ongoing.DataSource, AgencyOptions, EthnicityOptions, EmploymentTypeOptions, EmploymentStatusOptions,
                                     CategoryOptions, OutcomeOptions)
    AddHandler ST.SearchResultFound, Sub(result As Integer)
                                         'handle your result id here.
                                         MessageBox.Show("User selected row " & result)
                                     End Sub
    ST.Show()

End Sub
```

The advantage of this is that the SearchForm doesn't need to know what it's being used by. It's just there to give results which will make it easier to reuse later.

Comment: Instead of `AddHandler` you could have used `WithEvents`, then you do not have to worry about adding and or ***removing handlers***, that is what they are there for. Just a suggestion as then it will create the handles clause for you and will respond when the event happens.

Comment: I'll give this a go when I return to my project later. But it makes sense, so I'm sure it'll work!