# Calling 2 methods from 2 different forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have three WinForms .. Form1 Form2 and Form3

// Form1 Button

```
 private void btF1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form3(this).ShowDialog();
    }
```

// Form2 Button

```
 private void btF21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form3(this).ShowDialog();
    }
```

// Form3

```
      public partial class AjoutDemandeur : Form
{      
    Form1 _owner;
    Form2 _owner2;

    public Form3(Form1 owner, Form2 owner2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _owner = owner;
        _owner2 = owner2;
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _owner.methodForm1(); //call a method from Form1
    }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _owner2.methodForm2(); // call a method from Form2
    }
```

I want to call a method from Form1 and Form2 into the Form3
But the problem is in the two buttons btF1 and btF2
=> there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'owner2' of 'Form3.Form3(Form1, Form2)'
So any solutions !

Comment: Why don't you make them properties on Form3 that can be set from Form1 and Form2?

Comment: Form3 requires two parameters Form1 owner, Form2 owner2 and you are sending only one. Change form3 to require only one parameter, or change your calling methods to send two parameters - or make the second parameter of form3's constructor optional using the THIS keyword (google c-sharp optional parameters)

Comment: I would also ask the question "Is this a function that needs to run immediatly, or can it be run when the form closes". if it is the latter, you can use the `FormClosing` event handler

Comment: @Takarii yes I want to use it when Form3 closes .. but I think I have to call the function from the Form1 OR Form2 then use it in FormClosing Event .. is it right ?

Comment: Trying to make sense of this in my own head. The function you want to call is in form 1, but form 2 opens form 3?

Comment: You should not have to pass form references into other forms in order to do this. When you do a Form.ShowDialog(otherForm) the Form.Parent will be set to the calling form. Then you could do in Form3: if (Parent !=null && (Parent as Form2) != null) //Parent is Form2.

Comment: Take a look at this post which contains some good options for different situations: [Interaction between Forms - How to Change a Control of a Form from Another Form?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38769212/3110834)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !
Just I need to pass a null parameter in the calling methods

//Form1 Button

```
 private void btF1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Form3(this,null).ShowDialog();
}
```

//Form2 Button

```
 private void btF21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Form3(null,this).ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create events and their handlers in Form1 and Form2. Now fire those events from Form3.