# Cannot update datagridview from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

This is what i want to do . There is a datagridview inside a panel, this panel is inside a tabPage within a tabcontrol and this tabcontrol is in the Form1.

```
   Form1 --> TabControl  --> tabPage  --> panel  --> **DATAGRIDVIEW**
```

From my main form, I call Form2 such as Form2.Show() in which the user will input something then if the user click the button lets say "save changes" , the Form 2 will close and in the Form1, i want the datagrid to be updated. when the user clicked the button in Form2 Save Changes. Here's the code:

In Form1:

```
private void btnEditItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 form3 = new Form3();
    Form1 frm = this.MdiParent as Form1;
    form3.Show();

    this.Hide();  
}
```

In the second Form:

```
private void flatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Save Changes?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    {

        Form form1 = (Form)this.MdiParent;
        DataGridView dt = (DataGridView)form1.Controls["flatTabControl1"].Controls["tabPage5"].Controls["panelUpdateRequest"].Controls["dataGridRequestItemsUpdate"];
        dt.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "Plsss";**

        this.Hide();
        form1.Show();

    }
}
```

The Error:

> `Datagridview dt = (DataGridView)..Null Reference Exception.`

Comment: [Interaction between Forms - How to Change a Control of a Form from Another Form?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38769212/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

```
Form form1 = (Form)this.MdiParent;
```

Your this is your form 3 and not form 1. You need a reference of your form 1.

In Form 2 you need something like this:

```
public From3(Form1 form)
{
 // save the reference of the form 1 in form 3 to use it
}
```

Then you can call it from form1 with this:

```
form3.show(this);
```

hope it can help you

Comment: Sir, i kinda dont get it? Can you please explain further more?

Comment: @PoorGrammer "this" is a keyword to get the current instance of the class. You call "this.MdiParent" so the this is the reference of your form3. 
So it is clear that you get a null reference exception cause there are no gridview in form3. You need a reference of your form1 where your grid is.

To get the grid you need to pass the reference of your form 1 to your form 3.

Comment: So sir, what am i going to put inside public Form3(form1 form){}

Comment: @PoorGrammer
Yeah, kinda. 
You add variable Form1(for example here var) to your Form3 and the method below
public Form3(form1 form){ this.var = form; }
Then you use this "var" variable for this line
 DataGridView dt = (DataGridView)var.Controls["flatTabControl1"].Controls["tabPage5"].Controls["panelUpdateRequest"].Controls["dataGridRequestItemsUpdate"];
Now you open From3 and give it form1:
form3.show(this);

Hope you can understand it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function in your first form:

```
public DataGridView GetDataGridView()
{
    return this.dataGridRequestItemsUpdate;
}
```

And retrieve it in the second form:

```
Form form1 = (Form)this.MdiParent;
var dataGridView = form1.GetDataGridView();
```

Comment: Still the same sir. Got that null reference exception still :(

Comment: Are you sure you get it on the datagridview? Check if `form1` is not null.

Comment: Sir, where am i got to put the Form form1 = (Form)this.MdiParent;
var dataGridView = form1.GetDataGridView();