# Fill a List<String> of a Winform from other Winform while both forms are active

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, list, setter

I'm trying to fill a `List<String>` from another form while both forms are open.

In the form `WorkOrder` i have a list: `List<String> materialsList`, then in my other form `AddMaterials` i have other `List<String> list`, this is the list that i want to pass to the `WorkOrder` form, but both forms are open and i don't know it is possible to do that.

Here are my forms:

[image]

If i click the Add Materials button in the `WorkOrder` form then the form `AddMaterials` opens. Now with the form `AddMaterials` open, i fill one by one the elements of the list with the button Add new Material, then when i click finish i want to pass the `List<String> list` to the `WorkOrder` list: `List<String> materialsList`.

This is the code that i'm trying to solve this:

In the `WorkOrder` form:

```
List<String> materialsList = new List<string>();

public void setList(List<String> l)
{
    this.materialsList = l;
}
```

In the `AddMaterials` form:

```
public partial class AddMaterials : Form
{

    List<String> list = new List<string>();

    public AddMaterials()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Adding Materials
        list.Add(material.Text);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Passing the list with Method setList()
        WorkOrder o = new WorkOrder();
        o.setList(list);
    }
}
```

Any question post on comments.

Comment: [Interaction between forms — How to change a control of a form from another form?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38769212/3110834)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a reference to either the WorkOrder Form or the WorkOrder.materialsList in the constructor of your AddMaterials Form.
So your AddMaterials code could be

```
public partial class AddMaterials : Form
{
    WorkOrder wo;

    public AddMaterials(WorkOrder wo)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.wo = wo;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Adding Materials
        this.wo.materialsList.Add(material.Text);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }   
}
```

In WorkOrder you'd have this function which opens a new AddMaterials Form. You could place in logic here before you create a new AddMaterials Form to clear the list or do something else if you have multiple materials list for a WorkOrder.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add logic here to deal with multiple AddMaterial Forms 
    // on one work order
    new AddMaterials(this).Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is not working since you are using two completely different lists.
You can create a custom constructor for AddMaterials:

```
public AddMaterials(List<string> materials)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.materials = materials;
}
```

and declaring materials as a member of AssMaterials class:

```
private List<string> materials;
```

If you want to keep things even more separated you can pass a delegate:

```
public delegate void Del(string str);

class AddMaterials
{
    private Del addMaterialDelegate;

    public AddMaterials(Del AddMaterialDelegate) : Form
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.addMaterialDelegate = AddMaterialDelegate;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Adding Materials
        addMaterialDelegate(material.Text);
    }
}
```

and then from WorkOrder:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new AddMaterials(OnAddMaterialDelegate).Show();
    }

    private void OnAddMaterialDelegate(string material)
    {
        this.materialsList.Add(material);
    }
```

This will allow you to change your mind in the future without too much rework (for example if you want to switch from a List to a different type).