# Visual Studio C# using a function from Main form in a Dialog

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio, methods

When a button is clicked in Dialog window, the program must run `Test()` which is defined in the Main window.

**Main**

```
namespace Program
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        private __Dialog _Dialog = null;
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            using (this._Dialog = new __Dialog())
            {
                _Dialog.ShowDialog(this);
            }
        }
        public void Test()
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

**Dialog**

```
namespace Program
{
    public partial class __Dialog : Form
    {
        public Main p;
        public __Dialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            p.Test();
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error message:

> **NullReferenceException was unhandled**
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Program.exe
>
> System.NullReferenceException {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

What can be done to fix it?

Comment: You forgot to pass an instance of the main form to the other form. Take a look at this post:[Interaction between forms — How to change a control of a form from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768737/interaction-between-forms-how-to-change-a-control-of-a-form-from-another-form). *Example 4 - Create public Method or Property in first Form and pass an instance of First Form to constructor of second Form* is what you need.

Comment: Huh? You just defined `p`, you didn't actually tell `__Dialog` that p was *equal* to anything. So of course you're going to get a NullReferenceException...