# How can I call the controls of a form from another form in winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a form called `frmDSNMain` and another form called `frmChainedRun` I want to access the `DataGridView` present in the `frmChainedRun` form from the `frmDSNMain` form. I tried to call directly by the form name as `frmChainedRun.gridName.Rows.Count` from the `DSNMain`. But I am not able to fetch:

```
If frmChainRun.rbtnPredefinedModule.Checked = True Then
    If frmChainRun.grdPredefined.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In frmChainRun.grdPredefined.Rows
            Dim isSelected As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells(0).Value)
            If isSelected Then
                row.Cells(0).Value = False
            End If
        Next

    End If

ElseIf frmChainRun.rbtnCustomModule.Checked = True Then

End If
```

Comment: [Interaction between forms — How to change a control of a form from another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768737/interaction-between-forms-how-to-change-a-control-of-a-form-from-another-form)

Comment: There are multiple useful options in the linked post with some examples. The linked post is also linked to some other useful answers which describe how you can access controls of an other form. The most simple option for you probably is making the `DataGridView` public, so you can easily use its properties. But it's not the best option.