# How to make the list of Items displayed in the dataGridView to be (filtered?)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to do this?

From the users perspective, C# Winforms, as user types into a search textbox, I want the list of Items displayed in the dataGridView to be (filtered?)

Here’s what is currently happening:

dataGridView uses a list of items as its datasource similar to this:

dgv.DataSource = _myItemList;

Each item of _myItemListhas 2 properties (id, description)

Below the dgv there is a textbox in which user can search for items in the list

Currently, when user types in the textbox , a filtered _myItemListappears below  (the same way this filtered list appears is what I want to happen with the dgv)

The auto stuff happens with this code

foreach (var item in _myItemList)
            {
                string word = item.Description;
                textBoxCollection.Add(word);
            }

```
        textBoxSearchEmployeeList.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        textBoxSearchEmployeeList.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        textBoxSearchEmployeeList.AutoCompleteCustomSource = textBoxCollection;
```

Eg, if user types "Vac" into the textbox, all strings in _myItemList starting with "Vac" will appear.  Then as user continues to type the items in dgv will decrease.  So that when user types "Vacation" into the textbox, then the dgv displays only one row, "Vacation".

If it’s unclear what I’m trying to do, please let me know.

Comment: It depends to the type which you use as data source of your `DataGridView`. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40279675/auto-find-and-display-objects-when-input-keywords-in-vb) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I didn't understand wrong, you are looking for this,

I have created simple `DataTable` with rows. (you can see at gif) And I have a `textbox` to filter. Here,

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataView dv = (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView;
            dv.RowFilter = "Name Like '"+ textBox1.Text +"%'";
        }
```

**Result;**

[image]

Hope helps,

Comment: So after implementing your solution ...  doing it your way requires me to convert my List<someObjectWithProperties> myList into a DataTable.  How to do it without the DataTable?

Comment: @greg search over your list by using linq, then set it as a datasource at the end of text changed event.