# Using a ComboBox to filter my datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, filter

I have an application in which I have a database which is connected to a datagridview, and I want to filter this datagridview database with a ComboBox. But I can't figure out how to do it. I tried to do the same as I did with my textbox but that didnt work:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = string.Format("CONVERT(" + dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName + 
                     ", System.String) like '%" + textBox1.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

Comment: What didn't work, did it throw a error, or simply not filter the data?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - Did you check on the resulting filter string? This usually help a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this (you said `combobox` so I used `SelectionChangeCommited`),

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Propertyname= '{0}'", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388502/how-to-make-the-list-of-items-displayed-in-the-datagridview-to-be-filtered/40390374#comment68302302_40390374)

Hope helps,