# Global object instance?

Tags: c#, class, object, instance, global

I want to create a global instance and don't know if its possible, take the following for example

I have a String_Example Class:

```
namespace Pass_Object_as_Reference_Example
{
    public class String_Example
    {
        public string _str {get;set;}

        public String_Example(string Cadena)
        {
            _str = Cadena;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Form1 code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form  
{
    String_Example cadena;

    public Form1(ref String_Example str)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cadena = str;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cadena = new String_Example(textBox1.Text);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

This is my Main code:

```
static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            String_Example test = null;

            Form1 frm = new Form1(ref test);
            Application.Run(frm);

            MessageBox.Show(test._str);
        }
```

This is what I imagine would happen:

1. Create "test" object null
2. Pass the object as reference to the form
3. Form construct takes the "test" reference and assign it to object "cadena" (since they are objects and are passed by reference I would guess that Cadena now has the address of test)
4. when the button in form 1 is pressed the constructor is called and the textbox string is assigned, the form is closed
5. Use a messagebox to check the string in the test object (which should have the string assigned in form 1 but all we have is a null reference.

I think that when I'm calling the constructor I'm destroying the first reference and that is why the final object is `null` right?

Should I create the object in the main code and just modify the parameters in the subsequent forms?

Comment: one word: `static`...

Comment: Next: `ref` doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: singleton? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: What is the exact requirement? Singleton pattern may be helpful here.  It will create only object of class for the entire application. You can change it anywhere and you will get the updated status where ever you access it. If that's not the requirement then please explain about your use case .

Comment: Homework? [Here is essentially the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41751807/463206). The answers should be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What your code is doing

1. Create "test" object null

You actually aren't creating an object.  You are setting `test` to a null reference.

2. Pass the object as reference to the form

You are actually passing a reference to a reference to `test`.  If you just want to pass a reference, remove the `ref` keyword.  The value of a variable that is a reference type is already just reference to the object.  A ref object is not a reference to an object but a reference to an object reference.  See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx) if this is not clear to you.

3. Form construct takes the "test" reference and assign it to object "cadena"

You are populating the variable `cadena` with a null.

3a. (since they are objects and are passed by reference I would guess that Cadena now has the address of test)

No.  It has the value of `test`, which is a null reference.  I think you are trying to store a reference to an object reference (i.e. a pointer to `test`).  You are in fact only storing a pointer that is equivalent to the value held in `test`, which in this case is null.

4. When the button in form 1 is pressed the constructor is called and the textbox string is assigned, the form is closed.

Correct

5. Use a messagebox to check the string in the test object (which should have the string assigned in form 1 but all we have is a null reference.

There is no code in your example which goes back and populates `test` with a valid reference.

### Why this will never work

If you want to pass a pointer to a variable, you will need to use unmanaged code, according to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb(v=vs.140).aspx):

> **In an unsafe context**, a type may be a pointer type, a value type, or a reference type. A pointer type declaration takes one of the following forms:

(emphasis added)

You can't do it in c#... and in c++ I wouldn't do it, either, since there is no guarantee the pointer will get garbage collected.  That's why this pattern is not allowed in managed code.

### How to do what you're trying to do

I'll give you three options. There are probably a few more (Singleton, ByRef<T>, etc.) but I think these are the most common.

**Set up parent/child between program and form(s)**

If you are writing an app where you have a series of forms that need to access global state, one common pattern is to make the `Program` itself the container for global state, and pass it as a `parent` parameter to anything that needs it.  So here's your code again, following this pattern:

```
public class String_Example
{
    public string _str {get;set;}

    public String_Example(string Cadena)
    {
        _str = Cadena;
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form  
{
    readonly Program _parent;  //Reference to class which contains global state.  readonly = can only be set in constructor and can never change.

    public Form1(Program parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _parent = parent;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _parent.test = new String_Example(textBox1.Text);
        this.Close();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public String_Example test;  //Notice this is now a member variable

    static public void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        test = null;

        Form1 frm = new Form1(this);
        Application.Run(frm);

        MessageBox.Show(test._str);
    }
}
```

**Make the global variables static**

Or, if you don't want to pass pointers around to child objects, you can make the global variables `static`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form  
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program.test = new String_Example(textBox1.Text);
        this.Close();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static public String_Example test;  //Notice this is now a static variable, so it can be accessed without a reference to an instance of Program

    static public void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        test = null;

        Form1 frm = new Form1(this);
        Application.Run(frm);

        MessageBox.Show(test._str);
    }
}
```

**The "best" way**

The best way, or the most modern way that seems to be trendy these days, is to

1. Create a class (or classes) specifically intended to contain global state
2. Implement the state variables as member variables
3. Use a factory like Autofac to get an instance of the state container(s)
4. Tell the factory you only want a single instance no matter how many times you call it

For example

```
class ProgramGlobals
{
    public String_Example Test {get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void SetupFactory()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<ProgramGlobals>().SingleInstance();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        SetUpFactory();
        var globals = Container.Resolve<ProgramGlobals>();
        globals.Test = null;

        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        Application.Run(frm);

        MessageBox.Show(globals.Test._str);
    }
}

public partial class Form1: Form
{
    private voide button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var globals = Container.Resolve<ProgramGlobals>();
        globals.Test._str = new String_Example(textbox1.Text)
    }
}
```

You are free to use whatever [IoC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921087.aspx) toolkit you want, e.g. [AutoFac](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-lifetime-scope) or [Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664762(v=pandp.50).aspx).  This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581791/how-do-the-major-c-sharp-di-ioc-frameworks-compare) compares the major IoC libraries that are available for .NET.

This method is preferred because it allows a unit tester to provide their own stub for global state without [mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325053/difference-between-shims-and-stubs), which is often the hardest part of setting up unit tests.

Note that in the example above I am getting references to ProgramGlobals with executing code.  You can also set up your objects to get a reference automatically, using [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).  Great topic, but my answer is already pretty long, so you may have to research that on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you made things more clear now.

Comment: Hello, I tried using the parent-child pattern but i get this error when sending "this" as a parameter to the form: "Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer"

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve what you want without using [global state](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil) is to use some class like:

```
public class ByRef<T> 
{
    public T Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }   
}
```

Then in `Main`:

```
var byRef = new ByRef<String_Example>();
Form1 frm = new Form1(byRef);
```

And in `Form1`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ByRef<String_Example> cadena;

    public Form1(ByRef<String_Example> str)
    {
        if (str == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("str");

        InitializeComponent();
        cadena = str;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cadena.Value = new String_Example(textBox1.Text);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```