# How to add listbox items from another class using winforms app?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am trying to add items to listbox from another class.

I create a form, form name called **FilterControl**, it has a listbox control(**listBoxColumnHeaders**)

I create separate class called **FilterColumnHeader**, There I created one method()**addColumnHeader()**

Now I am trying to items to listbox of `FilterControl` form from this `FilterColumnHeader` class

Here is my code:

```
public void addColumnHeader(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            string query = @"SELECT 
                            AsHeading
                        FROM
                            RSHeading WITH(NOLOCK);
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.Connection = con;

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                FilterControl fc = new FilterControl();
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    fc.listBoxColumnHeaders.Items.Add(rd["AsHeading"].ToString());
                    MessageBox.Show(rd["AsHeading"].ToString()); //record is showing on message box
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ee.ToString());
        }
        
    }
```

**Note**

> If I try directly from the same form(FilterControl). It is working fine, Also the database is retrieved record successfully.
>
> I set the modifiers of listbox control to Public

Comment: `FilterControl fc = new FilterControl();` You are creating a new instance of the form, than the form which you see.

Comment: @RezaAghaei then how can I access that `FilterControl` properties in another class? Sorry I am new to winforms app.

Comment: [Interaction between forms — How to change a control of a form from another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38768737/3110834)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this accessing your form inside the class:

```
var fc= Application.OpenForms.OfType<FilterControl>().SingleOrDefault();
while (rd.Read())
            {
                fc.listBoxColumnHeaders.Items.Add(rd["AsHeading"].ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(rd["AsHeading"].ToString()); 
            }
```

Comment: thanks bro, It's working. I will accept your answer after 2 min