# Windows Forms - Change Datagrid Cell Value when Button in another Form is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have a value from Timer Form, which i want to set in a specific Datagridview Cell in the Main Form. When the new value is set, i want to update the Datagrid, so the right value is in shown in the Datagrid.

Thanks for your effort!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Communicate between two windows forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)

Comment: It is difficult to follow what you are asking as many things are vague. And you have described what you “want”… But you neglected to tell us what the problem is. What is not working as expected? This sounds like a common problem of communicating between two forms hence the duplicate link. From the posted pictures of code… `var timerFrom = new TimerForm();` creates a “new” `TimerForm`, however it is never displayed to the user… ? … In other words, the grids cell value may well be updated, but the user will not see this change since the form is never displayed.

Comment: I start from form 1 with a double click on a cell from the datagridview the timer form with the value from the clicked cell as start time.
Now I start the timer and stop it after a while. Then I take the stopped time and want to write it into the previously clicked cell or rather update it with the stopped time. The problem is that the datagridview cannot be updated from the timer form.

Comment: I think you are missing what I was saying from my last comment. If you look at the second code snippet picture you have posted… this is “creating” a NEW `MainForm` form with … `var mainForm = new MainForm();` … this is certainly legal… however, “that” form (`mainForm`) is NEVER displayed to the user. There should be something like… `mainForm.Show()` so the user can actually “see” the form.

Comment: In your code, the `mainForm` is NEVER displayed to the user and will go out of scope as soon as execution leaves the method. The code may very well set the `GetTimeFromTimer`, and call `RefreshDataGrid` … but this is being done on a form that no one will ever “see.” I am confident you will need to implement something like Karen’s answer or something similar in the duplicate link.

Comment: Ok, i will try, thanks.

Comment: [Interaction between forms — How to change a control of a form from another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38769212/3110834)

Answer (score 1):

Setup an event in Timer form and pass the value, here is a basic example. Adjust to work with your code in regards to your DataGridView and if the value being passed is not a string, change it.

```
public partial class TimerForm : Form
{
    public delegate void OnWhatEver(string sender);
    public event OnWhatEver WhatEverHandler;
    public TimerForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void WhatEverButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WhatEverHandler?.Invoke($"{sender:f}");
    }
}
```

Main Form, one button, one label

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OpenTimerForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimerForm form = new TimerForm();
        form.WhatEverHandler += OnWhatEverEvent;
        form.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void OnWhatEverEvent(string sender)
    {
        label1.Text = sender;
    }
}
```