# Passing list data between forms in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, pass-data

I want to use the last member of the list of form1 in form2, but I can't. I tried several methods, but I did not get the result and it sends Null. eaxListSM.Last() and eayListSM.Last()
SM is a acceleration signal which received from a gy-521 sensor.

and updated every 50 millisecods.

will I get the correct result if I use DataTransfer?

I also used the method of data and form reference.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SerialPort serialPort;

        // تعریف لیست ها
        public static List<double> axList = new List<double>();
        public static List<double> ayList = new List<double>();

        // تعریف تابع موج
        IEnumerable<double> eaxList;
        IEnumerable<double> eayList;
        IEnumerable<double> eazList;
        IEnumerable<int> eroundedAccResultList;
        IEnumerable<int> eroundedGyroResultList;
        public static IEnumerable<double> eaxListSM;
        public static IEnumerable<double> eayListSM;
        IEnumerable<double> eazListSM;
        IEnumerable<double> eaxListDF;
        IEnumerable<double> eayListDF;
        IEnumerable<double> eazListDF;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
            serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPort_DataReceived;
            Basketball.Click += Basketball_Click;
            this.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
            Form2 newForm = new Form2(this);

            eaxList = axList;
            eayList = ayList;
            eazList = azList;
            eroundedAccResultList = roundedAccResultList;
            eroundedGyroResultList = roundedGyroResultList;

            try
            {
                serialPort.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error opening serial port: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private Form2 form2 = null;

        private void Basketball_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
            if (form2 == null || form2.IsDisposed)
            {
                Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
                form2.FormClosed += (s, args) => form2 = null;
                form2.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                form2.Focus();
            }
        }
    }

    namespace Filtering
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// <para>Implements a Savitzky-Golay smoothing filter, as found in [1].</para>
        /// <para>[1] Sophocles J.Orfanidis. 1995. Introduction to Signal Processing. Prentice-Hall, Inc., Upper Saddle River, NJ, USA.</para>
        /// </summary>
        public sealed class SavitzkyGolayFilter
        {
            private readonly int sidePoints;

            private Matrix<double> coefficients;

            public SavitzkyGolayFilter(int sidePoints, int polynomialOrder)
            {
                this.sidePoints = sidePoints;
                Design(polynomialOrder);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Smoothes the input samples.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="samples"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public double[] Process(double[] samples)
            {
                int length = samples.Length;
                double[] output = new double[length];
                int frameSize = (sidePoints << 1) + 1;
                double[] frame = new double[frameSize];

                Array.Copy(samples, frame, frameSize);

                for (int i = 0; i < sidePoints; ++i)
                {
                    output[i] = coefficients.Column(i).DotProduct(Vector<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(frame));
                }

                for (int n = sidePoints; n < length - sidePoints; ++n)
                {
                    Array.ConstrainedCopy(samples, n - sidePoints, frame, 0, frameSize);
                    output[n] = coefficients.Column(sidePoints).DotProduct(Vector<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(frame));
                }

                Array.ConstrainedCopy(samples, length - frameSize, frame, 0, frameSize);

                for (int i = 0; i < sidePoints; ++i)
                {
                    output[length - sidePoints + i] = coefficients.Column(sidePoints + 1 + i).DotProduct(Vector<double>.Build.Dense(frame));
                }

                return output;
            }

            private void Design(int polynomialOrder)
            {
                double[,] a = new double[(sidePoints << 1) + 1, polynomialOrder + 1];

                for (int m = -sidePoints; m <= sidePoints; ++m)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= polynomialOrder; ++i)
                    {
                        a[m + sidePoints, i] = Math.Pow(m, i);
                    }
                }

                Matrix<double> s = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(a);
                coefficients = s.Multiply(s.TransposeThisAndMultiply(s).Inverse()).Multiply(s.Transpose());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private int ballX = 50;
        private int ballY = 50;
        private int ballSpeedX = 0;
        private int ballSpeedY = 0;
        private DateTime basketEntryTime;

        private Form1 parentForm;

        public Form2(Form1 parentForm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 50;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Update);
            timer.Start();

            this.parentForm = parentForm;

        }

     
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double eaxValue = parentForm.eaxListSM.Last();
            double eayValue = parentForm.eayListSM.Last();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, why you pass whole form to the another one ? just pass what parameters you want instead of form.
also you can use a global variable (static variable)

Comment: You just defined variables for those lists but never created a list at the variable and filled it with data.

Comment: You have a naming issue. So many Lists but no meaningful names. It does not help putting "List" into them get some meaningful names to really distinguish them and not get confused by all those names. It looks like that you are.

Comment: You don't "pass" data among Forms _at all_. You use a shared view model. Then you have the same data sources and can data bind to the same properties, which will update your UI Components automagically (given you set everything up correctly). See [Data binding overview (Windows Forms .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/data/overview?view=netdesktop-7.0)

Comment: You may also want to keep related data together. For example as properties of a class. So, instead of three `List<double>` you might want to have a ViewModel class that has a property of type `List<V3>` where `V3` is a class abstracting a 3D Vector? Just as an example.

Comment: [Interaction between forms — How to change a control of a form from another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38768737/3110834)